# Possible bad tag synonym

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

So a week or so ago, I made the [frw-universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frw-universe) tag; made a tag-wiki for it too. Recently, a certain someone (not relevant who) made it a synonym of [cosmology](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmology). For the record, it is currently the only synonym of [cosmology](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmology). I think this was not valid. I'd like to state my disagreement with this action and request that it be undone.

Cosmology is a broad field that applies to a very large number of topics. It is true that [frw-universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frw-universe) would be a subset of [cosmology](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmology), but it is not a synonym. [frw-universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frw-universe) only applies to topics that include a scale factor, are about the GR model of the universe we live in, and make some reference to the slightly more advance concepts like Friedmann equations, Hubble radius, co-moving quantities, or the like. Whereas cosmology can be applied to a much broader range, such as AdS/CFT, Schwarzschild space, asymptotically de Sitter solutions, and many others.

You could have a question that asks about the problem with using de Sitter space as a model for the universe we live in. That would be tagged as [cosmology](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmology), but it should not be [frw-universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frw-universe). Similarily, a question asking about cosmological redshift is a cosmology question and it is probably within an FRW-universe, but the question shouldn't be tagged as [frw-universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frw-universe) any more than a question about radioisotope dating should be tagged with [standard-model](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard-model) Additionally, a question that asks about finding the Ricci tensor for a higher-dimensional FRW metric could be tagged under [frw-universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frw-universe) (albeit, it would be more appropriate as [frw-metric](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frw-metric), but those would more likely be synonyms) and [general-relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-relativity), but I wouldn't necessarily put it under [cosmology](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmology).

Furthermore, if this is a simple case that 99% of the time when [frw-universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frw-universe) is used, [cosmology](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmology) will also be used, then I'd like to point out the existence of [dark-energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-energy), [space-expansion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-expansion), [big-bang](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-bang), or possibly the worst for that particular crime: [cosmological-inflation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmological-inflation). These are all allowed and often used without being recast as synonyms.

Based on all this, I think the synonymizing should be reversed.

Answer (score 3):

Well,

1. if the Phys.SE community thinks a [frw-universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frw-universe) tag would be useful, and
2. if somebody would like to be custodian over the [frw-universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frw-universe) tag, then it seems like a good idea to undo the synonym.

In an ideal world you are right: Let's tag all the questions as precise as possible. The problem is that we are only allowed to use 5 tags. And many users would not know the [frw-universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frw-universe) tag, and not use it. The fact is that currently almost none of the FRW-related questions are tagged as such. Thus it would require a custodian to

1. initially find all the FRW-related questions and tag them appropriately, and
2. in the future to tag new FRW-related questions consistently.

Comment: I've been slowly working at retagging old questions to frw-universe. And I try to tag new posts that deserve it, but in general most askers that don't know what it is don't ask questions that should be tagged by it

Comment: What tag _would_ people think to use when they are asking a question about the FRW metric? I think it would make sense to have that tag, or make that a synonym of [tag:frw-universe]. (Personally I would have called it [tag:flrw-metric] but I'm not in that field)

Comment: @DavidZ yeah, I was torn between metric and universe. I ended up choosing universe because I figured a question about the metric is also about the FRW-universe solution. But a question about the FRW-universe need not specifically reference the metric. That said, I'm not married to the choice